# SQL join two tables with same header

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables with the same header, table1 and table2. 
Table1:

```
AMS nr.     sample pos
G242        16
G243        14
G246        18
```

Table2:

```
AMS nr.     sample pos
G144        45
G789        32
G189        8
```

I want to add the data from Table2 in Table1 and store all data in Tabel1. Is this possible using SQL?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Do you want to insert data, so that there are 6 records in table 1 in the end or ist there any logic if AMS nr already exists in table1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at below query

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
    SELECT * FROM Table2
```

If you are trying to update the table content (for mysql):

```
UPDATE Table1 T1 
    JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.`AMS nr.` = T2.`AMS nr.`
SET T1.`sample pos` = T1.`sample pos` + T2.`sample pos`
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at below query.

```
Insert into table1([AMS nr.],[sample pos]) select [AMS nr.],[sample pos] from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (add the data from Table2 in Table1 and store all data in Tabel1) :

```
SELECT AMS_nr, sample_pos
INTO Table1
FROM Table2
```

A similar result but creates a new table:

```
select AMS_nr, sample_pos 
from Table1
union all
select AMS_nr, sample_pos 
from Table2
```

Comment: This is a product specific answer, but no dbms is tagged. At least specify which product it works for.